# How to ship a Windows Universal App with a predefined SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, win-universal-app

I have a predefined SQLite database and want to ship it with my App, so I can access it at runtime.
How do I achieve this?

Moreover, I want to Unit Test my app. So far the database file is referenced with the Unit Test Project as basis. Hence, my paths get broken.
How do I test a app like described above?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered to the similar question at MSDN forum. It may help you.

> I'm creating UWP app with SQLite.Net-PCL  I already have a SQLite db
>   that I want to use (I do not want to create a new one in the app).
>   I've copied it to the root of my project folder. How do I access it?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b6d7a970-0088-4bd4-aaa8-c86bca4387df/

Comment: ... why would you quote the *question* here instead of your answer?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How did you manage to test this code? When I try to execute a method which uses the `ms-appx:///...` path, the TestUnit project translates this path to its project path. Did you use links to mirror the file?